# Elasticsearch query with sorting by array of values

Tags: elasticsearch

Is that possible in ES to query and sort by array of values like for ex.

- Give me all results, but results with "country_code" = [ 'de', 'au', 'es'] should be prioritized at the given order like they are in array

It is possible???

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch does not really handle arrays, internally it's just same field having 3 different values: `country_code = "de" AND country_code = "au" AND country_code = "es"` all at the same time. You can though use [script based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#script-based-sorting) and handle arrays in Painless.